# whoosh index with django-haystack: fast under python 2.7 but really slow under python 3.7

Tags: python, django-haystack, whoosh

Using django-haystack with whoosh 2.7.4:
there is a huge performance difference under python 2.7 and python 3.7.

The virtual envs have same code and data, index size about 200M.

A basic simple search takes about 0.1 sec under python 2.7, but takes 5~10 sec under python 3.7, about 100 times slower.

From my test, the following whoosh calls take the bulk of the time under python 3.7:

```
index.searcher()
index.doc_count()
parser.parse(query_string)
collector.prepare(self, q, context)
```

Has anyone experienced the same?
Any advice how to boost whoosh performance under python 3.7? Thank you!